# Call in page content with ajax

Tags: jquery, load

I have some code working so when you click on the navigation it loads the href text in to the sliding content box.

However, I would like to load the pages #content into the #content on the page we are on with AJAX.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.php">gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="suppliers.php">suppliers</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
var lastData;
$(function () {
    $("ul li a").click(function(event) {
        loadData($(this).attr("href") +' #content');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

function loadData(data) {
    if(lastData == data) {
        $("#content-container").slideUp();
    } else {
        //$('#content').load(toLoad)
        $('#content').html(data);
        $("#content-container").slideDown();
         $('#close').click(function(){
              $('#content-container').slideUp('5000');
          })
    }
    lastData = data;
}
```

Any help would be great. I am so close yet so far... jquery is not my strongest skill.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastData;
$(function () {
    $("ul li a").click(function(event) {
        loadData($(this).attr("href"));
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    /* I'm assuming #close is added dynamically */
    $('document').on("click", "#close", function(){
        $('#content-container').slideUp('5000');
    });
});

function loadData(data) {
    if(lastData == data) {
        $("#content-container").slideUp();
    } else {
        $('#content').load(data);
        $("#content-container").slideDown();             
    }
    lastData = data;
}
```